# Python 3.4.2 tkinter Menu Auto Calling Function

Tags: python, function, tkinter, menuitem, python-3.4

I'm very new to python's tkinter gui and I am trying to use it to build a basic test.

I created the menu where one of the menu items must call a function although when I run the program I can see the output from the function before the menu item has been clicked and when the menu item is clicked it does not call the function.

My code is as follows

```
from tkinter import *

class cl_main():

    def __init__(self, master):

        lo_mainmenu = Menu(master)
        lo_mainmenu.option_add('*tearOff', FALSE)
        master.config(menu=lo_mainmenu)

        lo_menugroup = Menu(lo_mainmenu)

        lo_mainmenu.add_cascade(label="MenuGroup")
        lo_menugroup.add_command(label="Command", command=f_message())

def f_message():
    print ("This Function Has Been Called")

root = Tk()

co_main = cl_main(root)

root.mainloop()
```

I can't see what is wrong with it but I'm sure there is something horribly wrong here

Answer (score 2):

```
lo_menugroup.add_command(label="Command", command=f_message())
```

callbacks shouldn't have parentheses. As it is, `f_message` is called right away and its return value is assigned to `command`, rather than the function object itself.

```
lo_menugroup.add_command(label="Command", command=f_message)
```

Comment: omg, that's just ...I don't even know, if that's what fixes it I will throw myself off a bridge

Comment: yeah, that fixed it, wow I can't believe it but thanks so much